# How to extract content between a prefix and a suffix?

Tags: python, latex

I want to extract text from {inside} the curly brackets. The differences between those texts are the prefixes, such as `\section{` or `\subsection{` to categorize everything accordingly. And every end needs to be set by the next closed curly bracket `}`.

```
file = "This is a string of an \section{example file} used for \subsection{Latex} documents."

# These are some Latex commands to be considered:

heading_1 = "\\\\section{"
heading_2 = "\\\\subsection{"

# This is my attempt.

for letter in file:
    print("The current letter: " + letter + "\n")
```

I want to process a Latex file by using Python to convert it for my database.

Comment: 1) What if you have something like `\section{The equation $x_{1+2}=3}`? Here the end of the name is **not** the next `}`. Or  `\section{Name\label{label}}` often seen in some documents? *Any* regex solution is brittle, look for a proper LaTeX parser. 2)It's still not clear what you want to do. Do you only care for the titles of sections/subsections etc and want to collect them together with their level?

Comment: In my situation it is assured that the `{ }` are used only to end a section/subsection. I need to process the content to convert the Latex file into Cypher Code for my existing Neo4j graph database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the pairs `(section-level, title)` for all the file you can use a simple regex:

```
import re

codewords = [
    'section',
    'subsection',
    # add other here if you want to
]

regex = re.compile(r'\\({})\{{([^}}]+)\}}'.format('|'.join(re.escape(word) for word in codewords)))
```

Sample usage:

```
In [15]: text = '''
    ...: \section{First section}
    ...: 
    ...: \subsection{Subsection one}
    ...: 
    ...: Some text
    ...: 
    ...: \subsection{Subsection two}
    ...: 
    ...: Other text
    ...: 
    ...: \subsection{Subsection three}
    ...: 
    ...: Some other text
    ...: 
    ...: 
    ...: Also some more text \texttt{other stuff}
    ...: 
    ...: \section{Second section}
    ...: 
    ...: \section{Third section}
    ...: 
    ...: \subsection{Last subsection}
    ...: '''

In [16]: regex.findall(text)
Out[16]: 
[('section', 'First section'),
 ('subsection', 'Subsection one'),
 ('subsection', 'Subsection two'),
 ('subsection', 'Subsection three'),
 ('section', 'Second section'),
 ('section', 'Third section'),
 ('subsection', 'Last subsection')]
```

By changing the value of the `codewords` list you'll be able to match more kind of commands.

To apply this to a file simply `read()` it first:

```
with open('myfile.tex') as f:
    regex.findall(f.read())
```

If you have the guarantee that all those commands are on the same line then you can be more memory efficient and do:

with open('myfile.tex') as f:
    results = []
    for line in f:
        results.extends(regex.findall(line))

Or if you want to be a bit more fancy:

```
from itertools import chain

with open('myfile.tex') as f:
    results = chain.from_iterable(map(regex.findall, f))
```

Note however that if you have something like:

```
\section{A very 
    long title}
```

This will fail, why the solution using `read()` will get that section too.

---

In any case you have to be aware that the slightest change in format will break these kind of solutions. As such for a safer alternative you'll have to look for a proper LaTeX parser.

---

If you want to group together the subsections "contained" in a given section you can do so after obtaining the result with the above solution. You have to use something like `itertools.groupby`.

from itertools import groupby, count, chain

```
results = regex.findall(text)

def make_key(counter):
    def key(match):
        nonlocal counter
        val = next(counter)
        if match[0] == 'section':
            val = next(counter)
        counter = chain([val], counter)
        return val
    return key

organized_result = {}

for key, group in groupby(results, key=make_key(count())):
    _, section_name = next(group)
    organized_result[section_name] = section = []
    for _, subsection_name in group:
        section.append(subsection_name)
```

And the final result will be:

```
In [12]: organized_result
Out[12]: 
{'First section': ['Subsection one', 'Subsection two', 'Subsection three'],
 'Second section': [],
 'Third section': ['Last subsection']}
```

Which matches the structure of the text at the beginning of the post.

If you want to make this extensible using the `codewords` list things will get quite a bit more complex.

Comment: Wow. Excellent answer. The thing is: we still want to maintain the structure. If there is a heading_1, what are the belonging Headings_2? If there is a Heading_2, what are the associated Headings_3? And so on. How to change the regex to return nested dictionaries?

Comment: @Liam Just using regexes you cannot, however you can iterate over the result and group together consecutive subsections.  Now, this is very straightforward if you only have sections and subsections, if you want an extensible solution (say you want to track chapters too) then it gets a little bit more complex.  I'll edit my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use the regular expression module.

```
import re

s = "This is a string of an \section{example file} used for \subsection{Latex} documents."

pattern = re.compile(r'\\(?:sub)?section\{(.*?)\}')
re.findall(pattern, s)

#output:
['example file', 'Latex']
```